# How to change mandatory attributes to optional - @RequestBody - Spring boot REST service

Tags: json

For example, below is my JSON data which is being passed as @RequestBody for POST. How can we achieve the proposed system requirement.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBBaV.png)

Comment: Please go through the image attached.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.